# Why i get NotFound page if i am not redirected?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have on `Master Page` method `OnInit()`.
When i go to some page (`WantedPage.aspx`) where is missing some image, i go into method `OnInit()` 2 times : first when i go to `WantedPage.aspx` and second when i am "redirected" (don't know how to change "redirected" word) to error page because image not found. But realy after all i am still on `WantedPage.aspx`

Why in method `OnInit()` there are page `Error_NotFound.aspx`?

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        var tabooList = new List<string>
                        {
                            "ratings_search",
                            "ratings_latestratings",
                            "ratings_recent_releases"
                        };
        var pageName = this.Page.GetType().FullName; // here i get 2 different names : first as wantedpage and second as notfound
        if (!tabooList.Any(pageName.ToLower().Contains))
        {
            //Session["SearchParam"] = null;
        }
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

OnInit method.